# Could someone identify this yellow thing on a battery charger?

Tags: electrical

Picked up a battery charger at a garage sale, and I have no clue what this yellow thing is on the cable. If it's a connector, how does it come apart? Thanks for the help.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer TripleFault. Gently tried to twist or pull on what looked like the ends when I first got it but it didin't want to budge. Also, yes this was on the battery end of the charging cable. Came with a couple of extra quik connectors plus a cable with battery clips on one end. Again, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 20):

Those are inline fuse holders, with shrinkwrap over the ends. Pull it apart end-from-end to access the fuse. Unaffiliated example:

[https://www.amazon.com/Bussmann-HHB-Universal-Crimp-Holder/dp/B001PYN91M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001PYN91M)
[image: inline fuse holder]

Comment: My trickle charger only has one fuse and it's in the positive cable. How common is it to have two fuses? How does the this connect to the charger?

Comment: Just FYI, although you are unaffiliated, SE automatically currently turns all Amazon links into affiliate links.

Comment: Interesting, @EndAnti-SemiticHate! Does this mean I need to do something different when posting an example of an item that came from Amazon?

Comment: @JimStewart, I've only seen a fuse as close as possible if not directly attached to the positive side of the battery (at least that's where I put mine when I was maintaining a battery backup sump pump, and the master fuse on my cars are the same). Never saw a fuse on the negative side. The builder of this setup was either being very careful or didn't know it wasn't necessary. Also, going to guess this is the battery end shown.